# vba loop through multidimensional array based on defined array(6,12) for array(0,x)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to loop through an array using the values in the (0,x) {x=0-11 values}.  Should I be using the loop as above but be nested within a value incrementing loop?

```
DIM H as Integer
DIM vItem As Variant
DIM AssociateArray(6,12)    
...
data is populated into AssociateArray
...    
For Each vItem in AssociateArray
   debug.print vItem
   Select Case vItem
     Case "AAA"
       do this
     Case "BBB"
       do this
  End Select
Next
```

Comment: You should use loop if you are just to check `AssociateArray(0,n)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually only mean to loop through the same row number of each column with (0,x) ?

The following is an example of how that would work but uses (1,x) as data read in from worksheet creates a 1 based array not zero. Shows the logic though.

If you need to terminate at 11 you can do a loop to `UBound(AssociateArray,2) -1`

```
Sub test()

    Dim AssociateArray() ''Dim AssociateArray(6, 12)

    AssociateArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

    '(1 to 6, 1 to 12). Reading from sheet creates 1 based array not 0. Imagine actually 0 would replace 0 with 1 below

    ' (0,x)  would be (1,x)

    Dim x As Long

    For x = LBound(AssociateArray, 2) To UBound(AssociateArray, 2)

        Debug.Print AssociateArray(1, x)

    Next x

End Sub
```

Data in sheet:

[image: Data]

Comment: PERFECT! that's what I was after... I did adjust your code because I am not using Excel, it's Access.  I took a form that is populated by the end user and populate it into an array for a more organized layout of the captured data.  Which some of the data is from the form and some is from queries in gathering the data.  Thank you QHarr, you answered my question... it's dealing with the LBound and Ubound!  GREAT job on your explanation as with images you included...